# Lap timer in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0

Right, I've got a slight problem here, in which I've attempted to implement a lap timer.

In my protect override void update I've got this;

```
if ((IntersectPixels(destinationRedRect, car2redTextureData, startingLineRectangle, startingLineTextureData)))
{
    {
        redHit = true;
        _timer1 += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

What I'm saying here^ is, if car2red is colliding with the starting line, the timer begins, but if it's not, timer does not add seconds (it just stops_ . How can I make it so, if car2red hits the startingLine and moves forward a few pixels (without touching starting line) the timer still continues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a separate if statement like this:

```
if (redHit) {
    _timer1 += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
}

if ((IntersectPixels(destinationRedRect, car2redTextureData, startingLineRectangle, startingLineTextureData)))
{
    redHit = true;
    //Only use this line if you want to reset the timer to 0 when the player crosses that line again.
    _timer1 = 0;// I'm assuming that _timer1 is a double
}
```